# How to change multiple meta tag descriptions with a single variable (vanilla JS)?

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I have the following meta tags on my website:

```
<meta name="description" content="content here" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="content here">
<meta property="og:description" content="content here" />
```

All 3 of these meta properties are necessary on my site. However, is there a way to reference a single description in a JS variable that I can pass to each of these content attributes?

Comment: You could use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the querySelector with meta[key=value] and then set Attribute with setAttribute(key,value).

```
document.querySelector("meta[name='description'" ).setAttribute("content", "some new meta description");

document.querySelector("meta[itemprop='description'" ).setAttribute("content", "some new meta description");

document.querySelector("meta[property='description'" ).setAttribute("content", "some new meta description");
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I am still adding a description in three different places. This time, instead of adding the description in separate meta tags oh, I'm adding the description in separate JavaScript variables

Comment: @Millhorn You can put the selectors to an array and iterate that. `selectors = [  
  'meta[name="description"]',
  'itemprop="description"',
  'property="og:description"'
];

const content = 'some content';
selectors.forEach((sel) => {  
 let meta = document.querySelector( sel  )  
  meta.setAttribute("content", content)    
})`

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.

Comment: @Millhorn You got an error in the console? Can you share the error?

Comment: I didn't get a console error. It just didn't generate any meta data when I checked the page's source code.

Comment: @Millhorn You tried in the console: `document.querySelector("meta[name='description'").getAttribute("content");`  or you open an new browser tab to show the source?

Comment: Here's what I get in the Console: [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/1xep9b5)

Comment: @Millhorn the error message means that there is currently no meta field with this name in your DOM. Maybe it is called something else. If it does not exist and you want to have it, you can also create and add it with Javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238571/discussion-between-millhorn-and-maik-lowrey).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method of doing this

```
<meta class="meta" name="description" content="content here" />
<meta class="meta" itemprop="description" content="content here">
<meta class="meta" property="og:description" content="content here" />
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll(".meta").forEach((el) => {
        el.setAttribute("content", "your content");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.

Comment: @Millhorn, when tested, my code was able to successfully update each meta tag to have the content attribute of whatever you put in place of "your content". How did you test it and what were the results?

Comment: Curious... are you testing with Chrome, FF or Edge?

Comment: I tested in Chrome, and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let text = 'hello world';


let Allmeta = document.querySelectorAll('meta');

Allmeta.forEach((meta) => {
    if (meta.getAttribute('name') == 'description' || meta.getAttribute('itemprop') == 'description' || meta.getAttribute('property') == 'og:description') {
        meta.setAttribute('content',text)
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.